# Search module for taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

Having browsed through drupal.org with no results for D7, let ma ask the public: does anyone know of a Search module that would extend the search by taxonomy terms?
I have a very taxonomy-intensive site, where each taxonomy term has a rich description field, as well as its own term page. I want user to be able to find not only nodes but also taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend using [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) with which you can create an index and custom search from any entity including Taxonomy terms. You can then customize your search page using Views.

Comment: I like this answer as well, although the screencast available from the module page shows that a visitor should select what they want to search in. That's probably technically explained, but interface-wise it's not acceptable to me. A visitor doesn't have to have a clue as per the entity types and data organization on a site. They just want to find all occurrences of a string. They may care about types of results when they come, but not sooner. Also,  in a tiny search block consisting of only edit field and a button, where am I supposed to fit selectors? Will have to search more. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You don't have to set it up that way. Just select which entity you want to use when creating an index, create a view with that index, and the exposed search filter will work as your search block. It is transparent to the user what they are searching unless you tell them or expose a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) 
Included submodules
Custom Search Taxonomy: taxonomy options for the search block
Custom Search Blocks: provides additional search blocks, with different settings
Custom Search Internationalization

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this module. It has a bunch of nice functions, however one serious limitation (if I get it correctly). A hint in the content section says: `Choose which selector type to use. Note: content types and other searches cannot be combined in a single search.` That's too bad :(

Comment: This module no longer adds the Taxonomy search to advanced search

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar challenge where a large number of taxonomy terms contained valuable content that was not caught by the Drupal search index net. Our solution involved a small custom module. The module defines a custom content type with only a title field and term reference field. After a sitebuilder creates this custom node and chooses a taxonomy term to reference the standard node-centric index and search mechanism will find and display the custom node which contains only the title, term description as defined by referenced term, and a link to the taxonomy term page. By design this module requires a node to be created for each taxonomy term that the site builder wants represented. We created these nodes manually as not all taxonomy term descriptions were populated.

This basic module code is in 'sandbox' status.

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/dwaine/ttnode